# Why does File.each work but File.readline doesn't?

Tags: ruby

Why does `File.each` work but `File.readline` doesn't?

```
File.open('store-sample','r') do |f|

  f.readline("\n\n\n\n") do |l|
    binding.pry

  end
end
```

The code doesn't break however the following code works:

```
File.open('store-sample','r').each("\n\n\n\n") do |l|
  binding.pry
end
```

I don't know the internal implementation of these two methods, but this weird behavior really makes me crazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[readline](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-i-readline) doesn’t take a block; it returns a value.

```
line = f.readline('\n\n\n\n')
# do something with line
```

Comment: Every method in Ruby takes a block, the difference is if it does anything with it.  In this case, readline doesn't yield a given block, so the `bind.pry` is never evaluated.  Every method in Ruby returns a value.

Comment: @vgoff Thanks giving me better understanding of block in ruby

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [`File.foreach`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach)? It's designed to return a single line at a time.